# Reusable Navigation Bar Not loading with MMenus.js

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have started by trying reusable navigation bars. I have set them in navbar.html file for navigation bar code and i load it with scipt and jquery. I am now trying to use reusable navigation bar using MMenu.js but i am unable to get to the navigation bar to load and be interactive

Here is the index html and navigation bar html. I am using

Index html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="www.frebsite.nl" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />

    <title>mmenu.js demo</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dist/mmenu.css" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
   <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="nav-placeholder">

    </div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
    });
    </script>
    <!--end of Navigation bar-->
    
    <!-- mmenu scripts -->
    <script src="dist/mmenu.polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/mmenu.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Mmenu(document.querySelector('#menu'));

        document.addEventListener('click', function (evnt) {
            var anchor = evnt.target.closest('a[href^="#/"]');
            if (anchor) {
                alert("Thank you for clicking, but that's a demo link.");
                evnt.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

code for navigation bar html

```
<div id="page">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#menu"><span></span></a>
            Demo
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                <strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
                Click the menu icon to open the menu.
            </p>
        </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <span>About us</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <span>The team</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#about/team/management">Management</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#about/team/development">Development</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

                <li class="Divider">Other demos</li>
                <li><a href="advanced.html">Advanced demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="onepage.html">One page demo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

When i upload files it loads like this but it I am unable to get the menu to open and interact with it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwR75.png)

Comment: Or better yet without is there a way to make this navigation bar style resuable in a navigation.html file so i can just load it across all my pages     Using this style shown here  https://mmenujs.com/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Dont know how to close out this question.

My navbar.html file was missing scripts to make the menu/nav interactive. I added the scripts to navbar.html file. Everything runs smoothly